# Data won't parse in a document but will in dummy data in Python

Tags: python, parsing, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to run a script to parse data that is in a log. I believe the issue is in the with open statement or the way it is reading the keyword. When I enter the below all I get is 'WEB_SERVER_API' about 1000 times.

My code: *[edited after feedback from Banana]*

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

parsed_lines = []
to_find = ['QUERY_STRING','REMOTE_ADDR','HTTP_SERVER','CERT_SERIALNUMBER','CERT_SERVER_SUBJECT','CF_TEMPLATE_PATH','WEB_SERVER_API']

with open (r'C:/app/....', 'r') as log_lines:
    data = log_lines.read()
    log_lines.seek(0)  # Added after edit.
    for line in log_lines:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(line)
        parsed = {}
        for keyword in to_find:
            result = soup.find(text=keyword)
            if result and hasattr(result.parent.next_sibling, "text"):
                parsed[keyword] = result.parent.next_sibling.text
        parsed_lines.append(parsed) # Changed after edit.
print (parsed_lines)
```

If I add dummy data it parses correctly:

```
parsed_lines = []
to_find = ['QUERY_STRING', 'REMOTE_ADDR', 'HTTP_SERVER', 'OTHER']
log_lines = [
   '<td>QUERY_STRING</td><td>fa=string</td><td>REMOTE_ADDR</td><td>address</td><td>HTTP_SERVER</td><td>address</td>', 
   '<td>QUERY_STRING</td><td>second qs</td><td>REMOTE_ADDR</td><td>address</td><td>HTTP_SERVER</td><td>address</td>',
   '<td>OTHER</td><td>OtherValue</td><td>REMOTE_ADDR</td><td>address</td><td>HTTP_SERVER</td><td>address</td>'
   '<action>QUERY_STRING</td><td>fa=string</td><td>REMOTE_ADDR</table><saasd>address</body><title>HTTP_SERVER</td><td>address</title>'
]

for line in log_lines:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(line)
    parsed = {}
    for keyword in to_find:
        result = soup.find(text=keyword)
        if result:
             parsed[keyword] = result.parent.next_sibling.text
     parsed_lines.append(parsed)
print (parsed_lines)
```

Comment: @Banana I didn't see I had that line still in. I generally run it without the data = log_lines but I will try adding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After using `read()` there is nothing left to read. You need to tell python to start over from line 1:

```
(...)
data = log_lines.read()    
log_lines.seek(0) #read file from line 1
for line in log_lines:
    (...)
```

See [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) for more info.

**[EDIT]** Also, you have a mistake as you've written `parsed_lines.append(keyword)` instead of `parsed_lines.append(parsed)`.

Comment: I still just get a bunch of 'WEB_SERVER_API' or really which ever keyword is last.

Comment: That's because you append the keyword AFTER the loop. After the loop the keyword is the last item in the list. I think you wanted to append `parsed`? I've added it to my answer.

Comment: Yes that sounds right. So if I move in the indent it should bring about all of the keywords?

Comment: Yes. However, in your dummy example you append the parsed data, and for that it is the right place.

Comment: @OneBlindMan if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Hey! I will gladly do this for you when I can solve the issie. I apologize for the delay I was called elsewhere.

When I try thy the updated code by making the append even with the print I get the results: [{}]

Comment: I'm confused as to what the 'updated' code is - can you post it in an edit somewhere?

Comment: Your `parsed_lines.append(parsed)` is not indented. It should be the same as your dummy data example.

Comment: I have tried that on every indent possible and the result just changes the amount of the result I get it doesn't actually grab any data.

Comment: It's difficult to debug "doesn't grab any data". What does it output, when it's on same indent level as your dummy example?

Comment: [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}] except a lot more {}

Comment: Try adding `if parsed:` in front of `parsed_lines.append(parsed)` and see what output you get.

Comment: It returned [] and nothing more

Comment: That means your `soup.find(text=keyword)` never finds anything and never returns any result. Are you sure that your file has the right data? Because I see no other reason why the soup wouldn't find anything at all.

Comment: I will accept that as my answer and go through my data. Its about 3gb long so who knows. Thank you so much for the help.